GLFM table of contents - how to omit certain headings or limit the depth?
I'm new to Gitlab and I found that in the Gitlab-Flavored Markdown there's a [[_TOC_]] keyword for an automatic table of contents. Currently I use the Markdown All in One extension in VS Code for managing the TOC locally and it has the capability to define TOC heading levels and the <!-- omit from toc --> phrase for omitting certain headings.
The problem is if I use [[_TOC_]] it doesn't register the <!-- omit from toc --> designations and I don't know how to specify TOC level ranges.
Are either/both of those features available in the Gitlab/GLFM? If so, how would I accomplish them?
